# Particle displacement from pressure

Tags: acoustics

Is this correct? I'm looking for other sources of the result.

If pressure at a point is sinusoidal

$$
p=p_0 sin(\omega t)
$$

then particle displacement is

$$
\boldsymbol{s} = {1 \over {\omega^2 \rho}} \boldsymbol\nabla p
$$

where $\rho$ is the fluid's density.

I derived it by taking the 2nd time integral of particle acceleration ${\boldsymbol{a}} = {-1\over\rho} \boldsymbol\nabla p$.

Comment: It looks good, as long as you are not accounting for any viscous effects, which would change the conservation of momentum equation you are using.